# How to get multiple data using single flow?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to fetch the multiple table data using a single processor and push the data into respective tables using NiFi, For that which processors do I need to use? and what is the advantage of single flow instead of multiple flows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per [NiFi-5221](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5121) jira, Starting from NiFi-1.7 you can use ***[DatabaseLookupService](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-dbcp-service-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPoolLookup/index.html)*** controller service.

Now using lookupservice you can get more than one table data using the single flow.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239603/nifi-generatetablefetch-does-not-store-state-per-database-name) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848326/how-can-i-list-database-tables-in-a-set-of-databases-using-the-new-dbcpconnectio/51849473) links for more references.